# Azure Api Management add path parameter

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I am building a multi tenant application. We are not using Azure Active directory. 
We are using logic apps as a back-end services. Since each and every API url has a parameter tenant, we wanted to include at the API management level.

https://apm-eso-01.azure-api.net/{tenant}/v1/{siteid}/inventoryItems

**Is there any possibility to add path parameter to the host URL at the API Management level rather than including at the logic app as a relative path.**

Backend Urls. We have different instnaces/servers for each tenants

Tenant1 :
https://esous-devpd1.host.com/retail/data/esosm/api/v1-beta2/get/1

Tenant2:

https://esospanish-devpd1.host.com/retail/data/esosm/api/v1-beta2/get/1

APIM Urls

https://apm-eso-host-sbx-01.azure-api.net/lse/{tenant}/ esosm/api/v1/get/1

In-order to support the place holder for tenant at the APIM url/endpoints, I should add tenant place holder or path parameter to the backend url as below.

https://esous-devpd1.host.com/retail/data/esosm/{tennant}/api/v1-beta2/get/1

But all my urls should have tenant as a path parameter.

So my question is **can we add tenant place holder or path parameter to the APIM end point and just rewrite the backend server url as such to include the tenant parameter rather than adding it to the backend url**

Comment: I belive that I know what you are asking, but can you please add an example transformation (before/after) so that I am sure?

Comment: i have edited my question with more details

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by making sure that all operation URL templates in APIM start with /{tenant}/. Then you can add a policy at global or API level to make the transformation:

```
<rewrite-uri template="@{
  var operationPath = context.Operation.UrlTemplate.TrimStart('/').Replace("{*", "{");
  var result = operationPath.Substring(operationPath.IndexOf('/'));
  return ("/retail/data" + result).Replace("/v1/", "/v1-beta2/");
}" />
```

This policy will rewrite URI of current request by removing first segment from URI template. So if APIM receives request to `/{tenant}/xxx` operation it will rewrite it to `/xxx`.

And then you can add tenant as a query parameter by:

```
<set-query-parameter name="tenant" exists-action="override">
    <value>@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["tenant"])</value>
</set-query-parameter>
```

Comment: We have a integration layer (Logic Apps) between APIM and Back-end servers (Individual Tenant servers). We use logic apps to do invoke required back-end  services and aggregate the results. So the way we are mapping tenants is in logic apps ,we have a relative path parameter {tenant} and the same is been mapped to APIM. So in logic app based on tenant we will invoke corresponding tenant API's

Comment: As per my understating the answer provided is the other way of what i was looking.  My requirement is to pass tenant to the logic app end point as a query string parameter or some other way,  but do not specify the tenant as a relative path parameter in logic app while developing.

Comment: Ah, indeed that wasn't clear from the question. See updated answer.